# Accessing elements from a jFrame that is within a running instance of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am trying to make an app for communicating between different running instances of a thread. I have a jFrame that has a jTextField and a jButton. In the jTextField I type the number of threads that I want to run and after I press the jButton the threads run. Each thread contains a jFrame with a jButton. So if I type 3 in the jTextField and then press OK, three different jFrames pop out that have an own jButton. If I press the jButton in one of the jFrames of the threads, the jButton is set to disabled (`setEnabled(false)`). This should happen to each jButton of the jFrames from within the threads when pressed but the one from the last jFrame that is still not pressed.

This is the window class for the thread:

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    JFrame jr;
    JButton bt;

    public void run() {
        jr=new JFrame();
        bt=new jButton();
        bt.setTitle("Press Me");
        jr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jr.add(bt);
        bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                bt.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        jr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now this is how I run multiple instances of this thread. `i` is the number of the thread instances that is taken from the jTextField:

```
(    int i=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.gettext())  )

for (int a=0;a<i;a++) {
    Runnable thr=new Window(a);
    executor.execute(thr);
}
```

This is what I want to do: After I press the jButton on every jFrame that is within the thread instances and it is set to `setEnabled(false)` I get to the last jFrame that is popped up whose jButton is still unpressed. When I press this last JButton I want that all the JButtons on every jFrame to be set back to `setEnabled(true)`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main class it works 100 % now!

```
        import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

    /**
     *
     * @author oliver
     */
    public class Hauptklasse extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static int i = 0;
    static Random r;
    static boolean OkApasat=false;
    static int c;
    public static Fereastra[] thread;


    public Hauptklasse() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
        Image logo;
        logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resurse/logo.png"));
        jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(logo));
        jLabel4.setVisible(true);
        setLocation(200,100);
        jPanel1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        jTextField1.setEditable(false);
        jButton2.setEnabled(false);
        r=new Random();




    }


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(549, 448));

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Pornire");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Andale Mono", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jTextArea1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Numar maxim de ferestre");

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("OK");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 486, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)))
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                        .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 359, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 561, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 460, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         jTextField1.setEditable(true);
         jButton1.setEnabled(false);
         jButton2.setEnabled(true);
         jTextArea1.append("\n Welcome! :)");
         jTextArea1.append("\n The following app tests the communication between threads");
         jTextArea1.append("\n Please enter maximum number of windows to be opened");



    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       OkApasat=true;


    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        final Hauptklasse main1 = new Hauptklasse();


        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                main1.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

        while (true){
            if (OkApasat==true){
                if (Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())>=3){
                   i= (Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
                   main1.jTextArea1.append("\n"+i+" windows opened");
                   Fereastra[] thr=new Fereastra[i];

                    for (c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                        thr[c]=new Fereastra(thr);
                        thr[c].run();

                    }

                  OkApasat=false;
                   main1.jButton2.setEnabled(false);
                   main1.jTextField1.setEditable(false);


            }
                else jTextArea1.append("\n Wrong maximum number of windows-must be at least 3");

                OkApasat=false;
        }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Hauptklasse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }



    }

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

THIS IS THE WINDOW CLASS, WORKS 100 %:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author oliver
 */
public class Fereastra extends JFrame implements Runnable {

public JFrame jr;
public JButton bt;
public JLabel l;
public JLabel l2;
public Fereastra[] thread;
public boolean deblocat = true;

public Fereastra(Fereastra[] thread) {
    this.thread = thread;
    jr = new JFrame();
    jr.setSize(250, 250);
    jr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    bt = new JButton();
    jr.add(bt);
    bt.setText("OK");
    bt.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    l2 = new JLabel();
    l2.setText("Buton activ");
    jr.add(l2);
    jr.setVisible(true);

}

public void run() {

    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            bt.setEnabled(false);

            deblocat = true;

            for (int c = 0; c < Hauptklasse.i; c++) {

                if (thread[c] != null && thread[c].bt.isEnabled()) {
                    deblocat = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (deblocat == true) {
                for (int c = 0; c < Hauptklasse.i; c++) {
                    if (thread[c] != null) {
                        thread[c].bt.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My classes:

1) The Window class (Fereastra means window, deblocat means unlocked, buton activ means Button is enabled)

```
package concurenta;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author oliver
 */
public class Fereastra extends JFrame implements Runnable {

public static JFrame jr;
public static JButton bt;
public static JLabel l;
public static JLabel l2;
public static Fereastra[] thread;
public boolean deblocat = true;

public Fereastra(Fereastra[] thread) {
    this.thread = thread;
    jr = new JFrame();
    jr.setSize(250, 250);
    jr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    bt = new JButton();
    jr.add(bt);
    bt.setText("OK");
    bt.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    l2 = new JLabel();
    l2.setText("Buton activ");
    jr.add(l2);
    jr.setVisible(true);

}

public void run() {

    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            bt.setEnabled(false);

            deblocat = true;

            for (int c = 0; c < Hauptklasse.i; c++) {

                if (thread[c] != null && thread[c].bt.isEnabled()) {
                    deblocat = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (deblocat == true) {
                for (int c = 0; c < Hauptklasse.i; c++) {
                    if (thread[c] != null) {
                        thread[c].bt.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

2) The Main Class(a.k.a Hauptklasse, okApasat means ok is pressed):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package concurenta;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author oliver
 */
public class Hauptklasse extends javax.swing.JFrame {
static int i = 0;
static Random r;
static boolean OkApasat=false;
static int c;
public static Fereastra[] thread;


public Hauptklasse() throws IOException {
    initComponents();
    Image logo;
    logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resurse/logo.png"));
    jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(logo));
    jLabel4.setVisible(true);
    setLocation(200,100);
    jPanel1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    jTextField1.setEditable(false);
    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    r=new Random();




}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(549, 448));

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Pornire");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextArea1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Andale Mono", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jTextArea1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Numar maxim de ferestre");

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("OK");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 486, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
            .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 359, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 561, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 460, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     jTextField1.setEditable(true);
     jButton1.setEnabled(false);
     jButton2.setEnabled(true);
     jTextArea1.append("\n Welcome! :)");
     jTextArea1.append("\n The following app tests the communication between threads");
     jTextArea1.append("\n Please enter maximum number of windows to be opened");



}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   OkApasat=true;


}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


    final Hauptklasse main1 = new Hauptklasse();


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            main1.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

    while (true){
        if (OkApasat==true){
            if (Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())>=3){
               i= (int) (Math.random() * (Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()) - 3)) + 3; 

               main1.jTextArea1.append("\n"+i+" windows opened");
               Fereastra[] thr=new Fereastra[i];

                for (c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                    thr[c]=new Fereastra(thr);
                    thr[c].run();

                }

              OkApasat=false;
               main1.jButton2.setEnabled(false);
               main1.jTextField1.setEditable(false);


        }
            else jTextArea1.append("\n Wrong maximum number of windows-must be at least 3");

            OkApasat=false;
    }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Hauptklasse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



}

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}